# get_terms on save_post hook

Tags: publish, save-post, terms

Usually, if I want to check for some attribute of the post I'm about to publish, I will check like this:

```
$post_title = $_POST['post_title'];
```

post_title is the name of the title field in the edit window.

I thought I'd apply the same logic to the taxonomy meta box.

```
$formats = $_POST['tax_input[formats][]'];
```

Essentially, I'm trying to check if a specific taxonomy term is being selected when I publish a post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.

When you do something like this in a form..

```
<input name="tax_input[formats][]" />
```

You create levels in the `$_POST` array.

So you'd get the formats array like this...

```
<?php
$formats = $_POST['tax_input']['formats'];
```

Full example...

```
<?php
add_action('save_post', 'wpse74017_save');
function wpse74017_save($post_id)
{
    // check nonces and capabilities here.

    // use a ternary statement to make sure the input is actually set
    // remember that `save_post` fires on every post save (any post type).
    $formats = isset($_POST['tax_input']['formats']) ? $_POST['tax_input']['formats'] : array();

     // do stuff with $formats
}
```

Comment: Awesome, one question, in what format is the $_POST['tax_input']? Would it be slug, name, id?

Comment: It's going to be an array of the various `tax_inputs` -- just a standard array: numeric keys, string values.  On a regular post probably something like `array('category', 'format', 'post_tag')`.

Comment: And don't forget to `stripslashes_deep()` the `$_POST` values.

Comment: @chrisguitarguy Wouldn't this be a multidimensional array? Within category for example, you'd have any selected category terms. What format would those terms be? slug, name, id? I'm trying to figure out how I can test this.

Comment: Yep, multi-dimensional array.  The terms would likely be term ID's -- the quickest way to figure out would be to inspect element on those form fields.  What is the value?

Answer (score 2):

```
$formats = $_POST['tax_input[formats][]'];
```

???????

A `var_dump( $_POST );` could be helpfull

```
'tax_input' => 
    array (size=1)
      'post_tag' => string 'tag_a,tag_b,tag_c' (length=...)
```

Try this:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'find_post_tax' );

function find_post_tax(){

  $tax_to_fetch = 'supersonicscrewdriver';
  $found = false;

  if( isset( $_POST['tax_input']['formats'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['tax_input']['formats'] ) ){
    $taxs = explode( ',', $_POST['tax_input']['formats'] );
    $found = in_array( $tax_to_fetch, $taxs );
  }

  return $found;

}
```

Comment: Works just expected but I used foreach() to make an array to check the found. ```$taxs=[]; $post_array = $_POST['tax_input']['formats']; foreach( $post_array as $array_id ) { $taxs[] = $array_id; }```